# Exponential Distribution with Parameter

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

Suppose a widget's working lifetime (in years) is an exponential random variable with parameter = 1/2. What is the probability that the widget will keep working for another 1 year if it has been working for 3 years.

X~Exp(1/2)

E(X)=2

V(X)=4

I am stuck at this! Not too sure on how to continue. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

If $X$ has an Exponential distribution,
$$\mathbb P\{X\geq m+n\mid X\geq m\}=\mathbb P\{X\geq n\}.$$

Comment: Would this mean that m=3, n=1 ?

Comment: @student404 : That is what it would be. It wasn't entirely clear whether your question is about how to find $\Pr(X\ge1)$ or about deducing that that is what you need. At any rate, if you can find $\Pr(X\ge x)$ then that plus the definition of conditional probability, plus understanding that the event $\big[ X\ge3\ \&\ X\ge4\big]$ is the same as the event $\big[ X\ge 4\big]$ will enable you to prove the assertion that "Surb" has made. $\qquad$

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the explanation! 
P{ (X > 3+1 ) | ( X > 3) } = P { (X > 1) }.
So my answer would be e^-1/2 = 0.6065. 
Not sure is it correct not!

Comment: @student404: yes it's correct

Comment: @Surb Thank you so much for the hint!! :)